# Where is libcofi_rpi.so?

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi

I successfully cross-compiled a simple hello-world.c program for Raspberry Pi Board on my Ubuntu 12.04 host machine by following the instructions given in this

http://hertaville.com/2012/09/28/development-environment-raspberry-pi-cross-compiler/

The cross compilation command used was 
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc hello-world.c

I executed the a.out thus generated on the Rasperry Pi board and it displays the correct output.
Next I did

> ldd a.out

and got the following result

```
 > ldd a.out
   >>/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so (0xbcfcb000)
  >>>libc.so.6 ==> /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6e91000)
 >>>>/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6fd8000)**
```

Now, I am unable to find the file libcofi_rpi.so on my host Ubuntu 12.04 machine. So I am wondering how did the hello-world program get cross compiled in the first place.
If I rename the libc.so* cross compiler arm libraries on the host Ubuntu 12.04 machine, the cross compilation fails. So I know, the cross compiler is definitely looking for these libraries.
**How then did the cross compilation succeed without the libcofi_rpi.so library on the host Ubuntu 12.04 machine?**

Comment: http://intrepidusgroup.com/insight/2012/08/raspberry-pi-wheezy-and-her-non-non-executable-stack-nx/  this might helpful

Answer (score 1):

Compiling against a shared library will only require the header file.  Linking will happen at runtime (`ldd` checks whether all the dynamically linked libraries are available without actually running the program).

If you were linking the library statically (ie, compiling it into the final executable), then the compiler would have produced an error.

Comment: security note: `ldd` *does* actually run the program, so don't use it to analyze viruses.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have a `/etc/ld.so.preload` file containing the mentioned `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so`.
This is a library supposedly containing assembly-optimized `memcpy`, `memmove` etc. functions.
If your system does not have this library in the specified place and yet it works fine, then you can safely remove the line from the file (or remove the whole `/etc/ld.so.preload` file altogether, if this is the only line it contains).